# How to show relation data in dropdownlist with Yii2

Tags: join, drop-down-menu, yii2

I have 3 tabel :

- Plan2 = id_plan2,id_plan1,target
- Plan1 = id_plan1,Id_indicator,target
- Indicator = Id_indicator,name

In view _form plan2 I want fill id_plan1 from tabel Plan1 but show the name of indicator

How to make it

In Plan1 model I make function

```
public function  getIndicator()    
{
        return $this->hasOne(Indicator::className(), ['Id_indicator' => 'id_indicator']);
}
```

In view _form Plan2model

```
= $form->field($model, 'id_plan1')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(plan1::find()->joinWith(['indicator'])->all(),'id_plan1', 'id_indicator'),
            [
                'prompt'=>'choose Indicator',

            ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try with `relationName.fieldName`:

```
$form->field($model, 'id_plan1')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(plan1::find()->joinWith(['indicator'])->all(),'id_plan1', 'indicator.fieldName'),['prompt'=>'choose Indicator'])
```

[column names are case insensitive - Mysql.](http://cosminswiki.info/index.php/MySQL_case_insensitive_table_and_column_names)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a relation based  on getIndikator you should use  indikator in joinWith

```
= $form->field($model, 'id_plan1')->
            dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(plan1::find()->joinWith(['indikator'])->all(),
            'id_plan1', 'id_indicator'),
        [
            'prompt'=>'choose Indicator',

        ])
```